# regex substitute two patterns in one match

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to do a find/replace in notepad++ where the string is similar to

```
<span class="CharOverride-1">Q</span>
```

With a single replace command I'd like the result to be

```
<span class="somethingNew">somethingElse</span>
```

This matches the two things I want replaced but I don't know how to form the substitution

```
(?<=<span class="(CharOverride-1)">)(Q)(?=<\/span>)
```

If possible I'd like to avoid doing something like this

```
(<span class=")(CharOverride-1)(">)(Q)(<\/span>)  

and

\1somethingNew\3somethingElse\5
```

Comment: Thanks for both of the answers.  I wasn't sure if there was a way to 'move on'.  The first thing I type in the replace box, replaces \1 then I was wondering if there was a special character that would tell it, now the next thing I type will replace \2

Answer (score 0):

You can simlpy use 3 captures groups:

Search:

```
(<span class=").*?(">).*?(</span>)
```

Replace:

```
\1somethingNew\2somethingElse\3
```

Don't forget to check the "regular expression" checkbox.

But, if I can give you a very personal advice: don't use Notepad++...

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression `(?<=<span class=")CharOverride-1">Q(?=<\/span>)` uses lookahead and lookbehind to find the string `CharOverride-1">Q`, but only where it follows the string `<span class="` and is followed by `</span>`. Use `somethingNew">somethingElse` as the replacement string.